# Cursor jumps accros the screen at random times

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I use Ubuntu **14.04 LTS**, with everything updated to the latest version, on a *Acer v3-p111-p1g3*. I love this laptop, but I have the following problem:

At random times the cursor starts jumping around the screen clicking on everything and making using my laptop impossible.

I tried to disable my unrecognised display, but it didn't work. Also I disabled my touchscreen, but that also didn't work. I love Ubuntu but because of this problem I'm thinking to switch to another distro.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing.  Cleaned my touchscreen and now it's all good.